# Emit object based particles orthogonal to faces on a grid / without overlap

Tags: particles, normals, emission

I'd like to emit these hexagon reference objects from the faces of another object in the same way that I can for this plane. Specifically, with the orientation of the hexagons relative to the normal of the face that emits it and on a grid, or at least without any overlap.
[image: emitted objects from plane on grid]

I found that I can emit object based particles from a non-trivially shaped object's faces with rotation set to normal when I set the emission distribution to jittered or random. However, I don't seem to be able to make it work for the grid distribution.
[image: emitted objects from sphere randomly]

Does someone know a way to get the grid distribution to work, which alternative approach to take to distribute and sequentially modify (e.g. scale or rotate) a reference object covering a target object, or if there is a way to prevent overlapping particles when using the random distribution?

Comment: emit from vertices instead of faces? maybe play with the randomness settings and also make sure that the emitted object's longest dimension is shorter than the distance between vertices.

Comment: Thanks. So generalizing beyond the sphere example above, my impression for the workflow would then be to first prepare the underlying mesh to have vertices in the desired grid structure and then use the particle system to emit from that. Sounds like a workable approach :)
Though, one does get overlapping particles then it seems due to the emission number being quite high if one wants to ensure that something is emitted from all vertices. Is there a way to disable these overlaps i.e. emission from the same point twice?

Comment: alas, there may be such a way, but I don't know what it is if it exists.